# Cannot deserialize object on request

Tags: c#, angular, request, payload

I have a model in c#, which is a collection as:

```
 public virtual ICollection<Salary> Salaries { get; set; }
```

Now in angular, I'm trying to send it as:

```
  const salary: SalaryModel =  {
          clientId: 1,
          profileId: this.profile.id,
          amount: this.salary.value,
          startDate: new Date(),
          endDate: null,
        }
        this.profileForm.patchValue({ salaries: salary});
```

The `profileForm` salaries looks like:

```
this.profileForm = this.fb.group({
salaries: [],
})
```

So when I try to do an API request it is returning:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})

The payload looks like this:

[image]

I did not see anything wrong with the payload; does someone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: The c# property you are showing is a collection, but the json you are passing back is an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting square brackets on salaries: [salary]

```
this.profileForm.patchValue({ salaries: [salary1, salary2...salaryN]});
```